# Help with Restricted content

Tags: ubuntu-restricted-extras

[image]
If I remove these items, am I going to have trouble running some softwares?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Ubntu restricted extras` package says right there that it includes codecs for audio and video. I believe it is merely removing the conflicting codecs that are already installed. You shouldn't miss anything, since what's being uninstalled will be replaced.

Comment: so it aint gonna be a problem, I believe :D

Comment: Shouldn't be @BharatThapa